# Confused about COUNT in redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In the code below, what is happening exactly? I understand that columns week_commencing and metric are being SELECT'd but I don't understand what the third column represents. So it takes distinct entries in the column "value" then counts these? I am struggling to understand what Column3 represents.

```
SELECT week_commencing, metric, COUNT(DISTINCT value) as Column3
FROM TABLE X
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Yes, for each week_commencing, metric combination. Execute the query and see.

Comment: Within each group, formed by combinations of week_commencing,metric, `COUNT(DISTINCT value)` will count distinct values from the `value` column. In other words, if, in a group, there are duplicates in that column, they will only be counted once.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(DISTINCT value)` will count the number of different ("distinctive") values of the `value` column, within the given group.

For example:

```
col1 col2 col3
A    A    Foo
A    A    Bar
A    A    Foo
A    B    Foo
A    B    Foobar
A    B    Foobar
B    A    Bar
B    A    Bar
B    B    Foobar
```

would return:

```
col1 col2 col3
A    A    2      (being Foo and Bar)
A    B    2      (being Foo and Foobar)
B    A    1      (being Bar)
B    B    1      (being Foobar)
```